# For a Cohen-Macaulay local ring grade and height are same

Tags: commutative-algebra, cohen-macaulay

In Matsumura's book ' Commutative ring theory' Theorem 17.4, page 135 its been proved that in a Noetheriam local ring $(A,\mathfrak m)$ for any proper ideal $I$, grade $I=$ ht$I$, where grade of an ideal is defined to be the maximal length of $A$ regular sequence contained inside $I$ and height of an ideal is defined to be the infimum of of ht$p$ where $p$ is a minimal prime ideal containing $I$. In general grade $\leq$ ht. For the other inequality let ht$I=r$. Then the book says that we can find $a_1,\ldots,a_r$ such that ht$(a_1,\ldots,a_i)=i$ for $1\leq i\leq r$. I can't see how can we get this.

---

I have an argument which directly says that we can find $a_1,\ldots ,a_r$ inside $I$ which is a regular sequence, where ht$I=r$. But my argument does not use that $A$ is Cohen-Macaulay, hence must be flawed. But I cannot find where it is wrong.

Let $r\geq 1$

Let $p_1,\ldots ,p_k$ are minimal prime ideals of $A$. Then $I\nsubseteq p_i$ for each i and hence by prime avoidance $I\nsubseteq\cup p_i$. Therefore $\exists a_1\in I $ such that $a_1$ is not a zero-divisor and hence regular.

Now let $r\geq 2$

We consider $A'=A/(a_1)$. Let $\overline{q_1},\ldots \overline{q_n}$ are minimal prime ideals of $A'$. Then each $q_i$ is a minimal prime ideal containing $(a_1)$ and hence ht$q_i=1$. Therefore $\overline I\nsubseteq\cup\overline{q_i}$ as ht$I\geq 2$. Then we can choose $\overline{a_2}\in\overline{I}$ such that it is a zero-divisor in $A'$. Hence $a_1,a_2$ is an $A$ sequence such that ht$(a_1,a_2)=2$. We continue this way...

---

Thank you in advance.

Comment: In order to find such a sequence, you need to avoid the set of minimal primes. To have a regular sequence, one needs to avoid the set of associated primes. In general, these two sets are different. Cohen’s characterization was that if $I$ is of height $h$ and generated by $h$ elements, then all the assoaiated primes of I is minimal and of height $h$.

Comment: @Youngsu Thank you. I now understand that I was only showing that each element was not in the minimal primes but zero divisors are the union of all associated primes and there might be embedded associated primes.